# Getting rid of the "Allocating an object of abstract class type" error

Tags: c++, pointers, abstract-class, juce

I'm trying to write a simple program and after adding some code, I stumble upon this guy:

```
juce::AudioProcessorEditor* BluePillAudioProcessor::createEditor()
{
    return new BluePillAudioProcessorEditor (*this);
}
```

It shows an error like in the title:

> Allocating an object of abstract class type 'BluePillAudioProcessorEditor'

...apparently my class "BluePillAudioProcessorEditor" is abstract? I tried modifying so much of the code and yet it doesn't look good. This one line is why I wasted my entire evening. I admit that I'm a beginner in writing in C++.

Here's the definition of that class:

```
class BluePillAudioProcessorEditor  : public juce::AudioProcessorEditor,
            public juce::FileDragAndDropTarget,
            public juce::Button::Listener
```

Comment: yes, you can inherit abstract methods and become abstract if one of your parents is abstract and you didn't implement their non-implemented methods.

Comment: What's the _complete_ error message? Most compilers will tell you what pure virtual methods haven't been overridden.

Comment: *"Here's the cpp file if it's needed:"* -- There's no need to guess "if needed". Copy the code from the question, compile it, and see if this is enough to reproduce the error. The less code in the question while still reproducing the error, the better.

Comment: Make sure to reduce all code in your question to a [mre]. Large dumps of unnecessary code make your question hard to understand and not as useful to future visitors. If a line can be deleted without changing the meaning of the question, it should be deleted.

Comment: `juce::FileDragAndDropTarget` has a few pure virtual methods, e.g. `isInterestedInFileDrag` or `filesDropped`. Your class derives from `juce::FileDragAndDropTarget` but doesn't implement those methods. If you aren't interested in processing file drops, why did you derive from `juce::FileDragAndDropTarget`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you are a saint, I just removed that one, since I've been handling drag and drop manually! the code works now

PS apologies if I pasted too much code, I didn't know to which part it could be linked to.

Comment: @dawidowski give the [mre] (MRE) link from earlier a good read-over. Not only does it outline the Gold Standard for code examples for use on this site, but it's also a distillation of several common divide and conquer debugging techniques. Make a MRE early in the troubleshooting process and often you're done the troubleshooting early. And when you still have a problem after you've isolated it, you either A) are missing something fundamental (and will get an answer almost immediately) or B) have one bad mother of a problem that'll need an expert. Exactly the kind of question we like around here